# Error while running curl command through java

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to run the following curl command through java.This runs properly from the command line, but throws error when i run it using java

`curl -XPOST -H'Content-type: application/json' "http://localhost:8084/druid/v2/?pretty" -d'{"queryType":"timeBoundary","dataSource":"wikipedia"}'`

This is the java code using processbuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
            "-XPOST",
            "-H", "Content-Type:application/json",
            "http://localhost:8084/druid/v2/?pretty",
            "-d", "{\"queryType\":\"timeBoundary\",\"dataSource\":\"wikipedia\"}"

        );

Process shell = pb1.start();
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "-XPOST": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at com.druid.DruidConnection.main(DruidConnection.java:69)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 1 more
```

Comment: You need to have a space between `X` and `POST`. The same applies to other options as well

Comment: `"-X POST"` and `"X","POST"` . I have tried. both throws error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add curl.exe as a 1st parameter:

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
            "curl.exe",
            "-XPOST",
            "-H", "Content-Type:application/json",
            "http://localhost:8084/druid/v2/?pretty",
            "-d", "{\"queryType\":\"timeBoundary\",\"dataSource\":\"wikipedia\"}"

        );
```

Also you need to be sure that folder with curl.exe is in your PATH

PS. Of course it is for Windows, for *NIX just "curl"

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice.Thanks